# Select p tag after h2 that has a child with id

Tags: php, symfony

How can I select a p-tag that is after a  tag that has a specific child? Using a web crawler.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html

```
$crawler->filter('h2 span#hello + p')->each(function ($node) {
    var_dump($node->html());
});
```

Example:

```
<h2><span id="hello">Hi</span></h2>
<p>I want this p-tag, that is after the h2 above</p>
 <p>me too!</p>
<a>Not me!</a>
<h2>lol</h2>
<p>yo, not me</p>
```

does not work.

Comment: This is a rather bespoke piece of screen-scraping. Do you have to use symfony2 or would you just weave your own PHP code?

Comment: It does not matter, I just need that info.

Comment: I updated, to clarify it is all p tags after h2, until someother tag comes up.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the changed question! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is usually best to traverse HTML using the DOMDocument class (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) but you could do it with a regular expression thus:

```
// put the example HTML code into a string
$html = <<< EOF
<h2><span id="hello">Hi</span></h2>
<p>I want this p-tag, that is after the h2 above</p>
 <p>me too!</p>
<a>Not me!</a>
<h2>lol</h2>
<p>yo, not me</p>
EOF;

// set up a regular expression
$re = "/<h2[^>]*>.*?<span[^>]*id=\"hello\"[^>]*>.*?<\\/h2[^>]*>.*?(<p.*?)<[^\\/p]/sim";
// get the match ... the (.*?) in the above regex
preg_match($re,$html,$matches);

print $matches[1];
```

Would output:

`<p>I want this p-tag, that is after the h2 above<p>`

`<p>me too!</p>`

Comment: Any example with DOMDocument ?

Comment: That's a little trickier (for me at least!) in this case which is why I suggested regex.